# how can I Pragmatically assigning Factor level and label

Tags: r

```
Country Age
France  44
Spain   27
Germany 30
```

I have an above table, I wish to use above table for machine learning however I dont wish to give factor like

```
dataset$Country=factor(dataset$Country,levels=c('France','Germany','Spain'),
                       labels=c(1,2,3))
```

Is there any way to categories my string against a integer label in factor method of R

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Please explain what your desired outcome is.

Comment: I have read a data set from a csv file, the country column contain , France,Germany and Spain. I want to apply machine learning , however I dont want to use hard-coded categories for Factor Function of R to prepare my data for machine learning algorithm.

How can I improvise Factor function to auto allocate label to level in a a string column

Comment: Still unclear to me, but note that `read.csv` will automatically convert string variables to factors with the value of the string as the label of the factor.

Comment: its not doing it , its reading like string and in table it remains as string when I run the following code then it converts string to integer  in the column Contry
dataset$Country=factor(dataset$Country,levels=c('France','Germany','Spain'),
                       labels=c(1,2,3))